# Duplicate Message using useOptimistic and Performance Issues in Chat Feature

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm working on a chat feature in my Next.js app using Firebase Firestore, and I'm encountering two issues:

```
// UserChatWrapper.tsx
const UserChatWrapper = ({ user, allMessages, sendMessageAction }: Props) => {
  const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);
  const chatsAutoScroll = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>("");
  const [optimisticMessages, addOptimisticMessage] = useOptimistic(
    allMessages.messages,
    (state: Message[], newMessage: Message) => [...state, newMessage]
  );
  return (
    <>
      <form
        ref={formRef}
        onSubmit={() => setMessage("")}
        action={async (e) => {
          if (!message) return;
          addOptimisticMessage({
            id: v4(),
            type: "text",
            deleted: false,
            sender: {
              username: user.displayName || "User",
              uid: user.uid,
            },
            recipient: "admin",
            content: { text: message },
            timeStamp: new Date(),
            edited: false,
            read_receipt: {
              delivery_status: "not_sent",
              status: false,
            },
          });
          setMessage("");
          if (chatsAutoScroll.current) {
            chatsAutoScroll.current.scrollTop =
              chatsAutoScroll.current.scrollHeight;
          }
          formRef?.current?.reset();
          sendMessageAction(e).then((res: { error: string }) => {
            if (res?.error) setError(res?.error);
          });
        }}
      ></form>
      {error && error}
    </>
  );
};
export default UserChatWrapper;


// page.tsx
const UserChatWrapper = dynamic(
  () => import("@/components/chat/ChatWrapper"),
  { ssr: false }
);
type Props = {
  params: { chatId: string };
};
const UserChatScreen = ({ params }: Props) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Conversation>();
  const user = Cookies.get("user") ? JSON.parse(Cookies.get("user")) : null;
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) redirect("/sell");
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      doc(db, "Messages", params.chatId),
      (doc) => {
        if (!doc.exists()) router.push("/sell");
        setMessages(doc.data() as Conversation);
      }
    );
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [params.chatId, router]);
  const sendMessageAction = sendUserMessage.bind(
    null,
    { timeStamp: new Date() },
    params.chatId
  );
  return (
    <>
      {messages ? (
        <UserChatWrapper
          user={user}
          allMessages={messages}
          sendMessageAction={sendMessageAction}
        />
      ) : (
        <div className="text-center p-8">Please wait...</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default UserChatScreen;
```

- Duplicate Message Issue:
  When a message is sent, there's a brief moment where it appears as a duplicate before updating.
  How can I prevent this duplicate message appearance and ensure that the update is seamless?
- Performance Issues:
  I've noticed potential performance issues with the current chat setup.
  Are there any specific improvements or best practices I can implement to optimize the performance of my chat feature?
- Overall Chat Setup:
  What are some recommended best practices for setting up a real-time chat feature using React and Firebase?
  Any suggestions on how to structure the components and manage state for a smoother user experience?

I tried removing the useOptimistic and using it plainly but the draw back there obviously is that messages take a little while before they appear, I also tried using startTransition and faced the same issue.

Comment: Posts on Stack Overflow should limit themselves to a single problem, to ensure they're most useful for future visitors too. I answered for your first problem below. --- If the second problem persists, I recommend opening a new post for that with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That should contain exact information about the "potential performance issues", as that's unclear at the moment. --- The third problem is likely to get closed if you post it as "best practices" are highly subjective. If you have performance problem, it's best to post those (with numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Answering "Duplicate Message Issue".

Since you use `onSnapshot`, the Firestore SDK already calls your local callback with the new data before it sends that to the server. As far as I can tell your `addOptimisticMessage` does the same, but that is not needed. You can remove `addOptimisticMessage` and depend on Firebase to handle the optimistic local update for you.